# Leer fichero TXT y convertir ciertos valores en variables

Tags: bash, archivo

Tengo que comparar los tamaños de unas carpetas para poder hacer un % de diferencia entre ellas y en función del resultado enviar un mail. Quiero hacer el `for` por cada carpeta SITE, las carpetas SITE se encuentran todas a partir de un directorio, .../backup/SITE1..2..3. Mi intención es cuando termine el SITE1 utilice las mismas variables para el SITE2.

---

La parte de coger tamaños de carpeta y sacar el % y el envío de mail por separado por cada carpeta ya lo tengo resuelto, pero me gustaría simplificar el código y por ejemplo tener un fichero txt con las rutas de las carpetas, que lo leyera hasta un carácter y usara las variables, cuando terminara que siguiera con el siguiente SITE etc

```
    :SITE1
    Carpeta1
    Carpeta1.bkp
    Carpeta2
    Carpeta2.bkp

    :SITE2
    Carpeta1
    Carpeta1.bkp
    Carpeta2
    Carpeta2.bkp
```

Quiero asignar los valores de Carpeta1,... a variables hasta que encuentre ":", en ese momento ejecutar un comando y cuando termine continuar la lectura de SITE2 y volver a asignar sus variables

Gracias!

Comment: Ojala pudieras poner mas información, empezando con el lenguaje que ocupas, y algo mas gráfico lo que pretendes hacer, saludos

Comment: Hola Oswalfdo, el lenguaje esta en el #tag.

Comment: Indicas _me gustaría simplificar el código_. En tal caso, ¿podrías compartirlo para que tengamos por donde empezar?

Answer (score 0):

Escribí el siguiente script, creo que puede ayudarte, solo necitas adaptarlo a lo que necesitas. Saludos.

```
comando=0
for linea in $(cat prueba.txt)
do
    if [[ $linea == :* ]]
    then
        comando=$((comando+1));
        echo    "EJECUTAR COMANDO"
        if [ $comando -eq 1 ]
        then
            echo "GUARDAR VARIABLES"
        fi
    fi
```

done

Comment: Gracias me puede ser de mucha utilidad. Aun no tengo claro como resolver el problema que tengo.

Comment: Sería de ayuda que dieras mas detalles

Comment: Debido al [_field splitting_](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) y [_pathname expansion_](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06), [no es muy recomendable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) usar construcciones de tipo `for linea in $(cat archivo); do ...; done`. [Es preferible](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while IFS= read -r linea; do ...; done < archivo`, aunque dicha solución [tampoco es perfecta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/243481).

Answer (score 0):

No te explicas muy bien o soy yo el que no te entiende. He entendido que quieres:

1. Leer de un tirón de sitio a sitio todas las carpetas.
2. Aplicarles a todas las carpetas una función.

Entiendo, además, que el formato del fichero donde tienes apuntadas las carpetas es arbitrario y tú fijas el que quieres. Así que yo eliminaría los dos puntos y simplemente, separaría un sitio de otro con una línea en blanco (si deseas mantener los dos puntos tampoco hay problema.

Yo lo resolvería así::

```
awk -F '\n' -v RS='\n\n' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i="\""$i"\""; print}' listado.txt | \
while read -r sitio; do
    eval set -- $sitio
    manipulacion "$@"
done
```

Y ya está: "manipulacion" es la función que ya tienes preparada según cuentas y que recibe como primer argumento el sitio (SITE1) y como resto de argumentos las carpetas. He complicado un poco el código para permitir que las carpetas (y el sitio) puedan tener espacios. Si quisieras mantener los dos puntos en el fichero no tendrías más que modificar un poco el bucle después del "set"::

```
sitio=${1#:}
shift
manipulacion "$sitio" "$@"
```